# How do I fix errors with CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH when running CakePHP 2.x on WAMP in Windows?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I just uploaded my project on server and everything works well but two stuffs:

1) It doesnt send emails with cakeEmail.

2) it doesnt let me to get edit sites of my products and gives me this error:

```
INVALID PRODUCT
Error: The requested address '/products/edit/13' was not found on this server.
Stack Trace
#0 [internal function]: ProductsController->edit('13')
#1 /home/o/olejevina/www/olvi.cz/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(473): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(ProductsController), Array)    
#2 /home/o/olejevina/www/olvi.cz/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(104): Controller->invokeAction(Object(CakeRequest))
#3 /home/o/olejevina/www/olvi.cz/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(86): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(ProductsController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#4 /home/o/olejevina/www/olvi.cz/app/webroot/index.php(111): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#5 {main}
```

I figured out that problem is probably in app/webroot/index.php
because on localhost I have:

```
define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', 'C:' . DS . 'wamp' . DS . 'www' . DS . 'cakephp' . DS . 'lib');
```

but when I change it on wamp. It makes same errors.

Does anyone know what to do please or how should CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH be like?

Thanks

Comment: Just comment it out. You dont need that path to be set with a default setup. with app and lib being in the same root folder as in your case it will work out of the box, and furthermore do so on all systems (even after deploy). so I never ever set that path.

Comment: It still shows the same error. But there might be a problem that it is in the folder /olvi.cz on my hosting, because I have domain olvi.cz. And not in the root folder.

Comment: Setup a proper virtual host enviroment - and it will work: http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/05/29/working-with-domains-locally/

Comment: But its already too late, if the whole project is done no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'lib');
```